# make strace print EUID

Tags: permissions, strace

I'm trying to debug a permission problem, but I'm having trouble finding out with which EUID the application is being executed at the moment of the error.

Is there a way to make strace print the effective user ID?

Answer (score 0):

`strace` can't do that.

*strace* uses a kernel's feature known as *ptrace*.

*setuid* is **always ignored** if a process is *ptraced*, even if root 
is ptracing to avoid a root exploit known as *[myptrace.c](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CAN-2003-0127)*.